# Why does $\overline{z \,\overline{w}}=2 \text{Re}(z \,\overline{w})$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> why does $\overline{z \,\overline{w}}=2 \text{Re}(z \,\overline{w})$?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you mean " why does $\bar{(\bar{z}w)}=2\Re(z\bar{w})$"

Comment: Do you mean $\overline{z \overline{w}}=2 Re(z \overline{w})$ ? If yes, then it is wrong. For example take $z=i$ and $w=1$

Comment: One relation that you may be thinking of is that $\Im(z\bar{w})=-\Im(\bar{z}w)$

Comment: @Fred yes that is what i mean

Comment: Then you are wrong, as my example shows.

Comment: @Fred my lecturer said that w*conjugate of z = z * the conjugate of w = (zconjugatew)conjugate and i dont understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is true is that for a complex number $z$ we have
$$
z+\overline z = 2\operatorname{Re}(z).
$$
So starting from the right hand side of what you are claiming we have
$$
2\operatorname{Re}(z\,\overline w) = z\,\overline w + \overline{z\,\overline w} = z\,\overline w + \overline z\, w \neq \overline{z\,\overline w}.
$$

Comment: what does the answer end up being for the second line then? (Thank you for proving my questions incorrect, i think i got confused)

Comment: @user639649 Not sure what you're asking for, all the things left of the $\neq$ are equal.